# Logstash not reading new log file

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I've setup both Elasticsearch & Logstash in my system. What I'm trying to do is - scan all my log file (in XML format) & send that to Elasticsearch.

My Logstash Config file-

```
input {
    stdin { }

    file {
        type => "tweet"
        path => "/var/www/html/suresh/elasticsearch/product_logs/xml/*"
        sincedb_path => "/home/suresh/Desktop/tools/logstash-5.5.1/logs/test.sincedb"
        # ignore_older => 60
        # discover_interval => 5
        # start_position => "beginning"

        codec => multiline {
                            pattern =>"^<tweet>"
                            negate => "true"
                            what => "previous"
                        }
    }
}


filter {
    xml {
        store_xml => "false"
        remove_namespaces => "true"
        source => "message"

        xpath => [
            "/tweet/user/text()", "user",
            "/tweet/post_date/text()", "post_date",
            "/tweet/message/text()", "tweet_message"
        ]
    }

    mutate {
        join => ["user", ""]
        join => ["post_date", ""]
        join => ["tweet_message", ""]
    }
}


output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        index => "twitter"
    }

    stdout { codec => rubydebug }

    file {
        path => "/home/suresh/Desktop/tools/logstash-5.5.1/logs/out.log"
    }
}
```

My Sample log file(XML format)

```
<tweet>
  <user>Tweet1</user>
  <post_date>2010-11-15T14:12:12</post_date>
  <message>Playing with logstash-Log1</message>
</tweet>
```

What happening is when I'm running my Logstash by the following command

```
sudo bin/logstash -f logstash-simple.conf
```

& put any new XML file in my source folder Logstash is not detecting any file & parsing that. But, the moment I'm shutting down Logstash by pressing `Ctr+C` it's detecting the XML file parsing that & sends data to Elasticsearh before getting Shutdown.

Don't know what's going wrong. Any insight!!!

Comment: A few try, that could help you. Maybe it is a problem with sincedb. If the files doesn't end with a newline feed it keeps open, so maybe you have a limit on the number of documents fetched and it doesn't go ahead. Another try could be to point the sincedb to /dev/null `sincedb_path => "/dev/null"` and choose a brand new directory, just to check if in this new environment the system is able to fetch and parse new documents.

Comment: @AndreaRomagnoli Thanks for the reply. I've tried both the approach which you've mentioned. But, not getting any luck. But, one pattern which I've noticed is "After creating a new log file when I'm dropping in the source folder nothing is happening. But, if I again open the same file from source folder & add 1/2 line break it's start working" . Don't know what exactly going on.

Comment: Have you tried adding some non-empty new lines, to check if new added lines (manually of course) are parsed correctly? Have you tried to create some minimal example to exclude configuration errors, adding one piece at time, to check which part is causing the issue? This could really help you figure out what's going on.